# Overheating Toshiba Satellite L655 Laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, overheating, fan, toshiba-satellite

I switched to Ubuntu from Windows roughly a week ago. So I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. I'm experiencing overheating problem with my laptop and sometimes it's turned off suddenly. I have a Toshiba L655 laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - 64bit. I installed lm-sensors package and measured the temperature. It is continuously increasing when I'm working (just web browsing ) I googled my problem and found few solutions given in some forums. To solve this first I installed proprietary video driver from "Software & Updates" -> "Additional Drivers" tab.(VGA = AMD/ATI - Mobility Radeon HD 5430/5450/5470) Yet it didn't make any improvement. 
Then I edited  /etc/default/grub and set

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi.power_nocheck=1"
```

and saved (found from a forum). After that I executed this command

```
sudo update-grub
```

and rebooted. Still no sign of an improvement. Then I installed another package

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
sudo tlp start
```

Nothing changed.

May be the problem is with my cooling fan , when I was using Windows the cooling fan functioned frequently and I didn't have any issue like this. Now with Ubuntu 14.04 cooling fan is almost not operating. Very rarely it comes and goes and at that time I observe the temperature goes down. I really appreciate if anyone can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: In a terminal, run top, and see if anything is running at 100%+ cpu (like mayge compiz).

Comment: No, nothing runs 100%, all are under 10% CPU usage

Comment: Try installing indicator-cpufreq: Press > CTRL + ALT + T Then, type > sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq Then login in again.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 uses kernel 3.13 and since 3.13 there is a major bug in controlling the fans!

I saw reports about affected HP and DELL laptops, and even Macbook Air. The symptom on my HP Compaq nx8220 is that the fan speed is set according to the temperature, but only once at boot time or when resumed after suspend! At boot time the temp is usually medium and the fan stays at medium speed. But after resume the temp is low, the fan stays off and the system overheats easily.

I was able to fix it today (July 13 2014) with a pre-release of kernel 3.13.0-32 from https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Careful users should wait a few days to get this fixed kernel as a normal update!

From what I have read the problem was a kernel patch called "ACPI / AC: convert ACPI ac driver to platform bus" which has now been reverted in kernel 3.13.0-31 and higher.